# Possible solutions on ensuring develop branch contains latest release branch bugfixes?

Tags: git, merge

For some background:
Our process is releasing every 2 weeks. One week before release we create a release branch. On the release branch, only bugfixes are merged. On the develop branch we continue merging features or bugfixes not relevant to the release.

In our case, we want to ensure that bugfixing happening on the release branch is immediately available on develop branch for the following reasons:

- The bugfix implementer is responsible for resolving merge conflicts with develop branch. If release branch is only merged once after release, the release manager then has to resolve all merge conflicts. This is not ideal in our setup since we all have distinct domain responsibilities.
- Reduce duplicate tickets since people might report bugs on develop that are already fixed in release branch (not happening that often but still).

We are currently evaluating possible solutions. The two solutions that have been brought up so far:

- When bugfixing from release branch, create two PRs, one to develop and one to release. This way the implementer can solve possible merge conflicts with develop.
- Merge bugfix to release branch and cherry-pick to develop.

My questions would be the following:

- Are there any suggestions on how to achieve this? Which solution would you opt for and why (either the ones mentioned above or also new solutions are very much appreciated!)
- Maybe there is a reason we should avoid going this way? Why are there no sources on solutions on this topic? (at least I haven't found any)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `release` branch is merged only one time in the `master` branch when the pre-delivery bugfixing is done.

And when your team fixes a bug in the `release` branch you can immediately merge this fix in the `develop` branch via a PR (or MR if you're using gitlab)

The following picture represents the common GitFlow.
[image: usual Git Flow]